# Apache Ignite spawns too much threads

Tags: .net, ignite

Apache Ignite works in Client-Server mode with one server and about 10 clients.
For now, the server is online for 9 hours and spawned more than 2000 threads with the name "Thread-xxxx", that do nothing and are in RUNNABLE state, as VisualVM shows.
What these threads do and why they weren't killed?

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem: I'm using Ignite.NET and I don't spawn Java thread directly. But I used QueryContinuous on the server's side and my ContinuousQuery handled events in async(with async keyword) method. This async method did his work well, but for some reasons the Java thread created by the implementation of Ignite.Net to deliver the event, didn't finish. After making the ContinuousQuery handling synchronous, the issue was fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately there is an issue where Ignite.Net fails to de-register threads.

Comment: In general, it does not make sense to use async within `ContinuousQuery` listener, because the API is synchronous. But yes, there is an issue with JNI and threads: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-9638